# how to modify(new look) default popup alert in magento 1.9.x

Tags: default, popup

how to modify and get new look default popup alert in Magento 1.9.x
Can you help me with anyone, please?
thank you!
[image: popup alert in magento]

Answer (score 0):

This popup is a default html alert box. You cannot style it. I would suggest, however, that you remove the line break in the error message.

Whenever debugging it is useful to disable the custom theme first to see if the issue is with your theme. Then local modules. And so on.

I usually recommend you [follow the standard Magento debugging guide by Sonassi](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/429/336).

Comment: i wont to remove <br/> tag. which file wont i edit?